# Storing content to display on page

Tags: html, angular

In my current application we have a service which responds with a XML.With the XML we do XSLT transformation to a HTML and display it on our web page(review,Tutorials).

My Question here is this the only way to store the content of the webpage and display it as required.

We are going to migrate to a Angular app.So do i still continue using the XSLT way or is there other better way to store the content of the page and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use native JSON communication, if possible. Or try to convert your data to a native JSON object - Angular (and javascript, really) can work much better and faster with the [native JSON itself](https://blog.cloud-elements.com/json-better-xml).

Although, f you want to display a html content, you can use the [innerHTML](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#property-binding-or-interpolation-) tag.

If you manage to get the data in a JSON, read more and learn about the angular tehcniques of [displaying data](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). I suggest you do the tutorial on angular.io :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you have  blog where and how will you store the content of each post.This is what i want to know.